# Name of septoplasty technique without nose tubes?

Tags: surgery, otolaryngology, septoplasty, intubation

I have a small [blog](https://ncomputers.org/2017/septoplasty) and want to motivate its readers to go and see a doctor if they have constant trouble in the nose.

In April 2017 i had a septoplasty and am very happy with the results :D

I have heard, that many doctors still using nose tubes. The doctor said his technique avoids the need of those tubes.

In order to provide clearer information, it would be great to know the english name of this technique?